# Merging a key value pair List while removing duplicates C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

```
var a1 = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
var a2 = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
```

I have these two above lists of key value pairs. I want to combine them while removing duplicates. I am pretty sure I can do this by using LINQ, but the examples I have seen do not directly apply because they do not specify the complete process from `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` to  `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. If the two lists contain the same key they will also have the same value, so it does not matter which one gets kept when they are merged.

Comment: Define "duplicate" - is it if they have the same key, or the same key and object? If it's "same key", if you have a particular key multiple times, but with a different RandomObject each time - how do you choose which one to pick?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Given the question, I assume it's a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` - hopefully the author will confirm

Comment: Yes it is a List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>. Sorry I am new to these types of objects. @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: No worries, fixed that

Comment: Objects with the same key will also have the same value. I would of used a regular list but I am working on someone else's code. @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: @RB. The last comment was for you I believe

Comment: You could store the larger list in a dictionary then add the shorter list items in a loop. Dups will be rejected by dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (as stated) you don't mind which of the duplicates is chosen, then:

```
var result = a1.Concat(a2)
               .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
               .Select(g => g.First())
               .ToList();
```

or, if you have a lot of items, a better way would be to use a (more efficient) `DistinctBy` implementation. This one's (more or less) from [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs).

```
public static class LinqEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));

        return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()
        {
            var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
            foreach (var element in source)
            {
                if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                    yield return element;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

then

```
var result = a1.Concat(a2)
               .DistinctBy(x => x.Key)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Couldn't you use the resultSelector form of `GroupBy` instead of a separate `Select`? `GroupBy(kv => kv.Key, (k, kvg) => kvg.First())` Also you need `ToList()` on the end since the answer was requested as a `List`.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, probably. I prefer the clarity of a separate `Select`. `ToList` added. Thx.

Comment: I would speculate the main reason the `GroupBy` solution may be less efficient than `DistinctBy` is separating out the `Select`. Internally, `GroupBy` uses a custom `HashSet` equivalent that should be just as efficient as `DistinctBy`.

Comment: @NetMage `GroupBy` has to accumulate the entire group rather than just the first encountered item. Splitting hairs when used over small sequences, but over a huge # of items with many dupes, it will make a difference. Maybe. I might test.

Comment: I would speculate the `HashSet.Add` in `DistinctBy` (don't get me wrong, which I love, though mine does no error checking) is about equal to the collection time in `Lookup`.

Comment: In LINQPad for two 1mil element `List`s, I get that `GroupBy` is 73% the time of `GroupBy`+`Select` and `DistinctBy` is 68% of `GroupBy` with 2500 keys, 77% / 67% with 100,000 keys, 66% / 63% with 10,000 keys and 92% / 43% with 900,000 keys. So `DistinctBy` is best but `Select` does slow it down, depending on size of answer.

Comment: Would it be possible to then convert this(result) to a List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>? @spender

Comment: @JMaklen I don't understand. In both my examples above, the result ***is*** `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`

Comment: If you want, you can also do a variant `var result = a1.Concat(a2)
               .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
               .Select(g => g.Distinct().Single())
               .ToList();` which ensures an exception in case the assumption that equal keys will automatically have equal values, is violated. Here `Distinct()` works by using `ValueType.GetHashCode()` and `ValueType.Equals(object)`. That could be (micro-)optimized if needed.

Comment: @spender I am 100% incorrect. Your right it is a List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>. My problem was I actual wanted to convert it to a SortedList<TKey, TValue>. I solved this by using the following: new SortedList<TKey, TValue>(yourResult.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));

Answer (score 2):

You are right you can do this in Linq. However, you have to be careful about how equality is implemented on your `TValue` (you have to be careful on `TKey` as well of course, but you said those were strings so equality is well-defined).

```
void Main()
{
    var a1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    var a2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

    a1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("A", 1));
    a1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", 2));
    a1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C", 3));
    a1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("D", 4));


    a2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", 2));
    a2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("E", 5));
    a2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C", 33));

    var distinct = a1.Union(a2).Distinct();

    foreach(var kv in distinct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key}={kv.Value}");
    }
}
```

This will print the following result:

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
D=4
E=5
C=33
```

Comment: `Union` is a "set union" meaning that, after the union, there can be no duplicates. As such, `Distinct` is superflous.

Comment: See [the docs for `Enumerable.Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) : "*Return Value* : An IEnumerable<T> that contains the elements from both input sequences, ***excluding duplicates***."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "two lists contain the same key they will also have the same value" You can do this:

```
var a3 = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
a3.AddRange(a1);
a3.AddRange(a2);
var a3 = a3.Distinct().ToList();
```

or:

```
var a3 = a1.Union(a2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you create a dictionary and iterate over your two lists and add them to the dictionary? The dictionary cannot have an identical key so use a try catch when attempting to add.

```
Dictionary<TKey,TValue> myDictionary = new Dictionary();

//Iterate over list
//add try catch to attempt to add key and value to the dictionary.
```